# mysql trigger not allowing to select from another table

Tags: mysql, trigger, mysql-5.7

I have the following snippet in a trigger on a table named `bugs`:

```
 SELECT 
        uat_reopened_stats.release_name
        (uat_reopened_stats.rate_bugs + qa_reopened_stats.rate_bugs + closed_reopened_stats.rate_bugs + done_reopened_stats.rate_bugs)

        INTO @releasename, @bugstotalreopenrate

    FROM
        qa_reopened_stats
        JOIN uat_reopened_stats ON qa_reopened_stats.release_name = uat_reopened_stats.release_name
        JOIN closed_reopened_stats ON closed_reopened_stats.release_name = uat_reopened_stats.release_name
        JOIN done_reopened_stats ON done_reopened_stats.release_name = uat_reopened_stats.release_name;


INSERT INTO release_stats (release_name, bugs_total_reopen_rate)
VALUES (@releasename, @bugstotalreopenrate)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    release_name=@releasename,
    bugs_total_reopen_rate=@bugstotalreopenrate;

END
```

However, when I execute it I get:

> ERROR 1305 (42000) at line 1: FUNCTION uat_reopened_stats.release_name does not exist

Why is this happening?

```
MySQL [jira_statistics]> describe uat_reopened_stats;
+---------------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| release_name              | varchar(45) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| rate_bugs                 | float       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a missing comma at the end of the second line.